# Allow large number of popups

Tags: javascript, html

I have done a automation to shutdown all computers in network using html and powershell. HTML page will contain list of PC and check box to select the required pc and a button shutdown.In javascript I loop all checked checkbox and open a window by using window.open. (ctrls[i].id will be PC name)

```
function SendIt(){
    var ctrls = document.getElementsByName('cb');
    var systems = [''] ;
        for (var i=0; i < ctrls.length; i++) {
          if (ctrls[i].checked){ 
                window.open('http://'+ctrls[i].id + '/portnumber/pagename')

              };
        };  
    }
```

But this will loop so many PC's so browser will block the popup of window and it fails. So shutdown of pc dont work. So now how can i allow all popup windows or I just want to  browser to navigate to that url(http://pcname/portnumber/pagename) and load it. Is there any method to do the same may be by using http request or something becasue i need not want the new tab also and i just want the perform the task which is done by that url.

Comment: Do you actually have to have a window open after your loop or is just triggering the command enough?

Comment: Actually that url inside the for loop performs the pc shutdown. i actually dont want to see a window open in browser actually. So i dont know whether is there any method to do the same without using window.open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open a new window to trigger a get request. Try using an xmlhttprequest.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('get','http://' + ctrls[i].id + '/portnumber/pagename', true);
```

In full:

```
function SendIt(){

    var ctrls = document.getElementsByName('cb');
    var systems = [''] ;
    var xmlhttp;

    for (var i=0, len = ctrls.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (ctrls[i].checked) { 
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('get','http://' + ctrls[i].id + '/portnumber/pagename', true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It didn't work . I have tested it for a single pc and found like window.open('http:PC21:8000/?action=System.Shutdown') works where as using same url using XMLHttpRequest as u mentioned didnt work. How to troubleshoot?

Comment: I just noticed I left off the send command. If you didn't add it yourself that's probably the reason. See my edit.